# Finding the zeroes in a function

Tags: functions, polynomials, roots

I have come across a problem on my trigonometry homework where we need to find the zeros of a function without the use of a calculator.

The Equation:
Given one of the zeros is $x=5$
$f(x) = x^3+2x^2-23x-60$

Is there a more efficient way to go about this problem than simply factor it out?

Comment: "trigonometry"?

Answer (score 8):

The sum of the roots is $-2$, so the sum of the missing roots is $-7$. The product of the roots is $60$, so the product of the missing roots is $12$. So the missing roots satisfy the equation $x^2+7x+12=0$.

Is this simpler? Probably not. But different.

Comment: This is based on the Vieta formulas, right?

Comment: Yes, that is what I used.

Answer (score 1):

Yes if one of the roots is $5$ it means $x-5$ is factor of the given polynomial.Dividing the polynomial by $x-5$ we get the quadratic equation $x^2+7x+12$. Now the roots of this quadratic equation are $\frac{-7+(49-4*12)^{\frac{1}{2}}}{2}$ and $\frac{-7-(49-4*12)^{\frac{1}{2}}}{2}$. Thus the remaining two roots are $-4$ and $-3$. In general if we have a quadratic equation $ax^2+bx+c$ it has roots $\frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$.
For dividing $x^3+2x^2-23x-60$ by $x-5$ take a look at [Polynomial Long Division](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_long_division).

Answer (score 0):

Since you're given a root, factoring is probably the most efficient way to solve this problem: [polynomial long division](http://www.purplemath.com/modules/polydiv2.htm) isn't going to be too tricky in this case, and since you're dividing a cubic $x^3 + 2x^2 -23x - 60$ by the linear polynomial $x-5$, you'll end up with a quadratic, which you could then use the quadratic formula on or factor to get the other two roots.

But, let's say you weren't given the root $x=5$, or just wanted to find another way to solve this.  What then?

Well, you could use the [cubic equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function), but that's probably overkill.  If it were me, I'd like to try integer (or, at worst, rational) roots before I got my hands messy with a bunch of radicals.  Fortunately, there's a way I can do just that: the [rational root theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) tells me what any possible rational root will look like, so I just have to try those.  For your polynomial, the possible roots are $$x =\pm 60, \pm 30, \pm 20, \pm 15, \pm 10, \pm 6, \pm 5, \pm 4, \pm 3, \pm 2, \pm 1$$
Of course, this is a lot of roots to check, but you could still conceivably do it.  And you only need to find one root before you can factor down to a quadratic and use the quadratic formula (or just factor).